# JSP executeQuery not working

Tags: oracle, jsp, executequery

I have a basic code but its not working. i don't know why. I checked throughout the code by printing after each line but it seems like executequery is giving me hard time. Need help from experts please

```
<%@ page import="java.net.*, java.io.*, java.sql.*, java.util.*" %>
<%
String url   = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE";
Connection   con = null;
Statement    stmt =null;
ResultSet    rs=null;
String uname=request.getParameter("uname");
String passwd=request.getParameter("password");

try
{
//*** Load the jdbc-odbc bridge driver
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();

    //*** Attempt to connect to a driver.
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "admin", "admin");

    //***  Create a Statement object so we can submit
    //***  SQL statements to the driver
    stmt = con.createStatement();

    String  query=("select username,password from users where username="+uname);

    //*** execute query and show result
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    int numCols = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
while (rs.next())
    {
        int i=0;
        for (i=1; i<=numCols; i++)
            out.println(rs.getString(i));
    }

    //*** close connection
    stmt.close();
    con.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

Comment: Post the error if any?

Comment: @Aniket: There are no errors. Its just not printing the username

Comment: Try to print all values in the database using `select *`. Check if that works.

Comment: @AnjanBaradwaj: Did it already been working on this small program for more than 4 hours now :(. Sometime it gives an error as java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "TEST": invalid identifier

Comment: The thing is you have missed out on using quotations for your string variable in the where clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement is probably throwing an error because you are not quoting literals.

Instead of this code:

```
String  query=("select username,password from users where username="+uname);
```

Try with:

```
String  query=("select username,password from users where username='"+uname+"'");
```

Or better yet, use parameters in your queries by using a java.sql.PreparedStatement. Just google for `java PreparedStatement` and you will find lots of examples.

Comment: Sometimes you have to try such queries in your database client and try to figure out from there.

Comment: @AnjanBaradwaj: I did a print before and after the line, the value was passing or else how did showed on screen then?

Comment: The problem is not with `uname`. It is with the missing quotes.